# Python: sub list of items depending on a certain value of the items, e.g. boolean

Tags: python, list, boolean, sublist

I have a list of similar objects, some of them have a certain value set, here more specifically a boolean flag:

```
myList = [WhatEver(..., True, ...), WhatEver(..., True, ...), WhatEver(..., False, ...), WhatEver(..., True, ...), WhatEver(..., False, ...), ...]
```

Is there a painless way in Python to get a sub list of items whose value is set to a specific value, here either `True` or `False`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is. [List comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are a very good fit for this:

```
[item for item in myList if item.flag]
[item for item in myList if not item.flag]
```

where `flag` is the name of `WhatEver`'s field that you want to check.

Comment: Just to be ultra-clear, this returns all the items with `flag` set to `True` or any other value that doesn't evaluate to `False` (empty containers, zero).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter):

```
filtered_list = filter(lambda item: item.flag, myList)
```

Comment: Indeed—Python docs even say 'Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to [item for item in iterable if function(item)] if function is not None and [item for item in iterable if item] if function is None.' @npe's has more upvotes than yours, but I wonder if yours is advantages in some cases... if so, I suggest you mention this in your answer.